# Visualizar archivo CSV en IE11

Tags: csv

Buenas, utilizo Windows 7 IE11. 
Resulta que de abrir un archivo CSV **siempre** me lo descarga cuando realmente lo que quiero es que se visualice en el propio explorador.
¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?
 Gracias de antemano un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo descargaría y abriría éste con un editor de texto tipo NotePad++.
Pero si lo que quieres es visualizarlo en el navegador entiendo que deberías descargarlo y asignarle IExplorer como programa predeterminado (Abrir con)

Comment: Hola Adrian, gracias por tu respuesta<br>
Quiero visualizarlo en el navegador. aún con el archivo .csv descargado si le asigno IE como programa determinado, tras abrirlo me aparece como si lo quisiera descargar.

Comment: Prueba esto: En IE8 menu Herramientas - Opciones de Internet - Solapa Programas - Programas Internet, en la ventana que te abre elige "asociar un tipo de archivo o protocolo con un programa", buscas todas la extension (*.csv*) la seleccionas y la asociasa IExplorer

Comment: Gracias de nuevo Adrian, ya tenía .csv asociado a IE como te comentaba antes y sigue descargándome los archivos en vez de abrirmelos